# Installing Python2.7 over Python3.3

Tags: python

I'm running Windows 7 and I currently have python 3.3 installed on my system. I need to install the python 2.7 interpreter so that I can work with some outdated code, and I don't want to uninstall Python 3.3. Does anyone know how to do this without reinstalling IDLE and duplicating the system files that python33 and python27 have in common? Thanks.

Comment: Consider reading [Using Python on Windows](https://docs.python.org/3/using/windows.html#python-launcher-for-windows) from the official docs -- it has some notes about handling multiple installed versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As both the python versions are installed in different folders, so you need not worry about it.

You can use set "PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\My_python_lib" command in windows to temporary change the default python version to use.

While working on the projects requiring different python, you can use virtual environment approach. The following link will help you on this topic: http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/
This is widely used concept by python developers.

Answer (score 1):

just install them in different folders.

Comment: So installing python2.7 with the full default install settings to a new folder won't cause conflicts between the two interpreters somewhere down the line?

Comment: Python3 will still work, but your `PATH` or `PYTHONPATH` may be automatically modified when you install Python2.7 -- check out link to the official docs in the comment to your question about how to resolve issues that may arise, and you'll be fine.  But yes, installing in different folders is a must.

Comment: @Danny it will be fine. i did exactly the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

When you install python 2.7 , it will be automatically be installed in a different folder just go into that folder and run python idle from there.